# Creating DNS CNAME or MX aliases

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record, cloudflare

How can I create a CNAME or an MX record alias, for example, I need smtp.mydomain.com to resolve to smtp.yandex.com so that on my email client I should enter smtp.mydomain.com instead of smtp.yandex.com. I am using CloudFlare as my DNS manager and my domain is registered on Godaddy.

Here is my CloudFlare settings page

[CloudFlare DNS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoVAE.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Solved: Solved the issue by setting the CNAME aliases on Godaddy panel instead of cloudflare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from setting up mail./imap./pop3./smtp.yourdomain.tld as a CNAME. But please be aware that you SHOULD NOT point your MX record to a CNAME.

**Solution 1:**

Setup a MX record to the yandex.com mailserver and CNAMEs from your domain pointing to the mailserver

**Solution 2:**

Setup a A record pointing to the yandex mailserver and use it when creating your new MX / CNAME records.